# Compiling ANSI C++ code on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, ansi-c

I'm struggling to compile and run a program on Mac OS X, which is written using ANSI/ISO C++ (Windows). [Source code](http://ws.cs.ubc.ca/~kevinlb/dl.php?u=cass-source.zip)

I've tried to compile using g++, and by importing the files and compiling using Xcode.

If i try to compile using g++ (command line), I get a couple of warning, which are easy to fix,:

> e.g. `warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’`.

But, i get some weird errors as well.

If i create a simple "Command Line Tool" project of Type "C++ stdc++", and import all the files in this project, it gives me a bunch of warnings and an error.

Can anyone please help me compile this sample source code? Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: There's no such thing as ANSI or ASCII C++. Did you mean ISO C++? Or did you mean C?

Comment: It didn't occur to you that we might need to see those "weird errors"? ;)

Comment: @David, i meant ANSI/ISO C++. @Jalf, i figured that since the code is available, anyone can try to compile it to see the problems.

Comment: Please do post the error messages; help the people to be able to help you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In stopwatch.cpp change the include at line 49 from strstream.h to sstream.
- In stopwatch.cpp line 50 change the include from fstream.h to fstream.
- In qsort.h change the declaration of `Qsort()` so the second and third parameters are `unsigned long` rather than `size_t`.
- In qsort.cpp change the definition of `Qsort()` so the second and third parameters are `unsigned long` rather than `unsigned`.

As a side note, the declaration and the definition of `Qsort()` didn't (necessarily) match in signature, and that's incorrect.

Comment: Awesome! I really appreciate you taking some time out to help me out. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

In qsort.cpp change the function decleration to:

```
 52 void __cdecl Qsort (
 53     void *base,
 54     unsigned long num,
 55     unsigned long width,
 56     int (__cdecl *comp)(const void *, const void *)
 57     )
```

So we just added `long` to `num`and `width`variables.

You will also have to fix simple problems like `#include <strstream.h>`-> `#include <strsream>`

Comment: I really appreciate you taking some time out to help me out. Thanks much.